# Not getting updated test in tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE for showing editor in my asp.net site for add and edit article functionality. My code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">        

    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "exact",
        elements: '<%=txtTextBox.ClientID%>',
        theme: "advanced",
        width: "650",
        height: "500",
        plugins: "style,advhr,advimage,advlink,inlinepopups,preview,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,wordcount",
        // Theme options            
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "undo,redo,separator,bold,italic,underline,separator,cut,copy,paste,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,separator,image,media,link,separator,forecolor,backcolor,separator,preview",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "fontsizeselect,fontselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        theme_advanced_font_sizes : "10px,12px,14px,16px,24px",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: false,
        relative_urls: true,
        remove_script_host: true,
        document_base_url: ""
    });        

</script>



<div>
    <textarea id="txtTextBox" runat="server" cols="500" rows="100"></textarea>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="Button2_Click" OnClientClick="return test();" />
</div>
```

This code adds whatever typed in editor in db as HTML. This works fine. For editing I just retrieve this article record and show content in 
    textbox on page load

```
   string sql = "select * from content_table where ID=1";
   comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);

   if (ds != null)
   {           
       txtTextBox.InnerText = Server.HtmlDecode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Content"].ToString());
   }
```

but problem is that I am not getting new changed text instead I only get text that I get on page load. why this is happening. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are updating the textarea - not the editor. For this use:

```
var new_content = Server.HtmlDecode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Content"].ToString();
tinymce.get('your_editor_id').setContent(new_content); // editorid equals your textarea id
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it's not working when I try to set new_content it shows me "Unable to get value of the property 'setContent': object is null or undefined" this error.

Comment: you will need to replace 'your_editor_id' with the real id. if that one is not presend and you are using one single editor you may use tinymce.editors[0].setContent(new_content);

Comment: I replaced 'your_editor_id' with my id but still it showing error. I tried to use tinymce.editors[0].setContent(new_content) again it fails. I am not getting setContent method in my code. Is there problem in setContent method?